# Does the Tenacious badge ever get removed?

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

I'm very happy to have been awarded the Tenacious badge and, as with many other users, have struggled to understand why I got it. After reading a number of related posts, I understand that now but I'm wondering if I still keep the badge if any of my existing zero-score answers get upvoted in future.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Badges once awarded are not taken back except tag badges.

Comment: I got it after one answer got accepted. Same answer got upvoted like 10 minutes later and I still have it.

Comment: @Mołot et al - many thanks, I'll wear it with pride now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give a quick tl;dr of the reasoning, badges represent an accomplishment you made *at the time* they were awarded. The fact that you no longer meet the criteria for the badge doesn't negate the fact that you once did, so the badge is retained.

The exceptions to this are tag badges. If you earned a tag badge and the tag was subsequently removed, then you *probably* should never have earned that badge in the first place as the tag was a mistake to begin with.

Be proud of it, hang it on the wall, give it a few extra rubs when you clean your monitor to shine it. You earned it, so you should keep it :)

Comment: Thanks - I'm already getting a frame made ... ;-)